# Changing opacity of included graphics without tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, includegraphics, transparency

I can make a figure translucent using the `tikz` package

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[opacity=0.5] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{myfigure.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But, I want to implement this *without* the tikz package (because for me `\usepackage{tikz}` slows down compile processes a lot).

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the transparent package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,transparent}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image.png}

\texttransparent{0.5}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image.png}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using `XeLaTeX`, and `transparent` package is not supported. Is there any alternative in my case?

Comment: @mariovilar with a current LaTeX you could load the new pdfmanagement by using \DocumentMetadata at the begin, then xelatex is supported (but not page breaks in the transparent text). But personally I would recommend to switch to lualatex.