# Strange behavior of \transparent

Tags: floats, transparent

In [Opaque figure without tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/668964/), I learned about `\transparent`, which makes things transparent.

One thing I cannot understand is the following:
When I run

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1
  \end{tabular} 
\end{table}
{\transparent{0.2}\lipsum[1-4]}
\end{document}
```

The table locates within the part made by the second `\lipsum` and becomes (unintentionally) transparent.
In contrast, when I run

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
{\transparent{0.2}
  \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1
    \end{tabular} 
  \end{table}
}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

The table again locates within the part made by the second `\lipsum` and (unintentionally) does not become transparent.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Transparent uses a "color stack". That means that it reinsert the opacity command after a page break and so it works over page breaks.  But that can also catch unwanted text parts (as color can). So use it with care.

Answer (score 3):

Place the command inside the floating environment (`table`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{table}[ht]
  \transparent{0.2}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1
    \end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can place `\transparent{1}` inside the floating env for the first example, and place `\transparent{0.2}` for the second example. This perfectly solves my problem. But I'm curious whether there is a fundamental way to solve this, not bypassing it.

Comment: @user182849 I'd say this is the fundamental way to solve it. The fact  that `\transparent` outside the table affects the table is mostly accidental due to lack of error checking. In general floating environments try to set document defaults and avoid inheriting settings from their position in the source file.